# Click a different button after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to auto-click a button in a page, but only after I manually clicked it first, the problem is that when the page loads, immediately the button starts to click and I need that it starts to click just after I make the first click

```
var $button = $('#start_autobet');
var maxWait = 3000;

function autoBet(){
    console.log("Clickeando...");
    $button.trigger('click');
}

setTimeout(function() { autoBet();}, getRandomWait());
```

I don't know how to make it start just after clicking.

Comment: I don't see where the "first click" comes in here.  According to this code, you are explicitly triggering a click on `#start_autobet` after `getRandomWait()` milliseconds.  Where is there another button or other click event anywhere?

Comment: Is there a click event even bound to that element?

Comment: Rather then triggering the `click` event you can call the function that the button calls in there or simply trigger the submit. What is it that the button does?

Comment: there's no bound click function your function is being executed after the timeout

Comment: prenvent default...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$('#start_autobet').on('click', function() {
 $(this).click();
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thaks! :D

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to do it like this if you want to click the button a second time after it was clicked and have a random wait time between clicks.

```js
var button = $('#button');
var maxWait = 3000;

button.click(function() {
  autoBet();
  setTimeout(function() { autoBet();}, maxWait);
});

function autoBet(){
  //console.log("Clickeando...");
  $("#output").append("Clickeando...<br>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">
  bet
</button>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Do you want the clicks to repeat after you clicked untill you click it again? (basically toggle an interval)????

Comment: No, I want them click until the page auto-reload itsefl, so, auto-click after my click is fine for now

Comment: You should use an interval for this, so you can clear it. It is safer than an endless loop...